# Sending serial signal of HT12A encoder by wire over 25 meters distance

Tags: microcontroller, serial, communication, encoder

This question has been asked many times, but I couldn't find something regarding sending out serial binary pulses from HT12A encoder over long distance.

The wire will be running beside of AC 220v wires, so will it work efficiently without noises or voltage loss ??

Comment: Long distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a twisted pair (one pair of a cat5e cable) or a shielded twisted pair if you are overly concerned, or convert to optical fiber if you are very overly concerned. 50/60 Hz is hardly ever a problem with unshielded twisted pair in practice.

If you are running one of those "data over power lines" devices in the building you might have more reason to be concerned, as those put high frequency signals on the power lines.

I haven't bothered to look far enough into the data sheet to find likely data rates, but back in the days of modems (current for some folks, still) data signals ran for many miles on UTP cables at rates up to 56 Kb.